# To prove that the centre of 2 circles and the two points at which the 2 circles cut and the origin lie on a circle.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Let the circles
$$x^2+y^2-2cy-a^2=0~~~~and~~~~x^2+y^2-2bx+a^2=0$$
with centres at $A$ and $B$ intersect at $P$ and $Q$. Show that the points $A,B,P,Q$ and $O=(0,0)$ lie on a circle.

My work:
I found out the centre of the 2 circles to be $A(0,c),B(b,0)$ and also found out that the points at the which circle cut, $P,Q$ are the common chord of both the circles. So,I found out the equation of the chord of the circle to be $bx-cy=a^2$. Now, I am stuck. I tried to figure out that these points are concylic by considering two quadrilaterals formed by these points but nothing to progress. Please help!

Comment: Hawk: I found a way in which one can show the five points lie on one circle, without getting the messy coordinates for $P,Q$, and put it at the end of my answer. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: I believe the coefficient of the $ \ y-$ term of your chord equation should be $ \ c \ . $

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes you are correct...it is actually a typo. Thanks for identifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$. Obviously, $\gamma$ contains both $A$ and $B$. Because $\angle AOB$ is a right angle, point $O$ is also on $\gamma$ by a converse of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle_theorem#Theorem) (more specifically, of [Thales' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem)).

Writing the circle equations in a more useful form
$$\begin{align}
x^2 + ( y - c )^2 &= a^2 + c^2 \\
( x - b )^2 + y^2 &= b^2 - a^2
\end{align}$$
we see that $|\overline{OA}| = |c|$ and $|\overline{OB}| = |b|$, and that
$$|\overline{AP}|^2 = |\overline{AQ}|^2 = a^2 + c^2 \qquad\qquad |\overline{BP}|^2 = |\overline{BQ}|^2 = b^2 - a^2$$

From right triangle $\triangle AOB$:
$$|\overline{AB}|^2 = |\overline{OA}|^2 + |\overline{OB}|^2 = b^2 + c^2$$

By interesting coincidence,
$$|\overline{AP}|^2 + |\overline{BP}|^2 = (a^2+c^2)+(b^2-a^2) = b^2 + c^2 = |\overline{AB}|^2$$
so that $\triangle ABP$ ---likewise, $\triangle ABQ$--- is *also* a right triangle. Consequently, $P$ and $Q$ are on $\gamma$ by the converse of the Thales' Theorem.

Comment: This should have been my actual approach, but I don't know why I didn't think of this...it is a very good solution, most obvious to try but the hints of the problem were overlooked by me.Though this should be represented differently by me, to properly answer the question but the hints you gave me were really good. Thank you!

Comment: Your application of Thales is very nice and your argument has the additional virtue of telling us the lengths of the chords $ \ AP \ $ and $ \ BP \ $ .  It follows, with a little more work, that $ \ AB \ $ is a perpendicular bisector of $ \ PQ \ . $  It is nice to see in the various answers here the variety of ways in which the theorems of circular geometry can be brought in.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By what you have found the center must be at $K=(b/2,c/2)$ since this is where the perpendicular bisectors of $OA$ and $OB$ meet. So far a circle with this center goes through the three points $O,A,B.$ Now you only need solve for the two circle intersections, and check their distance to $K$ is the same as from $O$ to $K$.

**Added:** It turns out the intersections of the two circles are a bit of a mess to find. However it turns out we don't need their expressions in order to prove all five points are concyclic.

Let the circle equations be labeled by their centers: $$A :\  x^2+y^2-2cy-a^2=0, \\ B: \ x^2+y^2 -2bx+a^2=0.\tag{1}$$
Now $B=0$ can be rewritten as $(x-b)^2+y^2=b^2-a^2,$ so that one must assume the right side of this is positive in order that $B=0$ denote an actual circle. We'll assume that.
For the intersection of the two circles $A,B$ we would solve $A=0,B=0$ simultaneously. This is the same as solving $(A+B)/2=0,\ (A-B)/2=0$ simultaneously. We have 
$$(A+B)/2=0:\ \  x^2+y^2-bx-cy=0, \\ (A-B)/2=0: \ \ bx-cy-a^2=0. \tag{2}$$

This pair of equations (when set to $0$) is really not easier than the direct pair $A,B$. But an interesting thing happens. If we take the circle through $A(0,c),B(b,0),O(0,0)$ we use its center $(b/2,c/2)$ and squared radius $b^2/4+c^2/4$, and find the equation of the circle through $A,B,O$ to be none other than $x^2+y^2-bx-cy=0$, which is one of the two equations of system $(2)$ we were to solve to determine where the two circles given by equations $A=0,B=0$ intersect each other. This proves that, even without getting the specific coordinates of these two other points $P,Q$, they must lie on the circle through $A,B,O.$ Conclusion: all five points on the same circle.

Comment: That means you are considering the circle to have diameter equal to the radius of both given circle. But why? This might not be true...atleast to me...

Comment: @Hawk  In the above all I'm saying is that, *if* there is to be a circle containing $A,B,P,Q,O$, then this circle must at least contain each of $A,B,O$. Given these last three are not collinear there can only be one such circle and it's center must be at $(b/2,c/2).$ [Note I did not check that the other two points $P,Q$ also lie on this circle, but assumed they must otherwise the problem would not be stated right.]

Comment: @Hawk is the sign correct on the equation of the second circle, i.e. one of the circles has $-a^2$ while the other has $+a^2$? [I'm still not done checking that the points $P,Q$ also lie on the same circle and would like to know the two equations are copied right...]

Comment: Yes, that is what is given in the question...though there may be some typo but the chance of being so is not more than 5%

Comment: @Hawk As it stands now the second circle after completing the square is $(x-b)^2+y^2=b^2-a^2.$ So one must assume $b>a$ in order that this circle not be empty, which seems odd in a problem set up like this, unless it was mentioned.

Comment: Square? Are you sure it is not a typo? Because I have no idea how a square forms...please give me a little more hint.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12690/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-hawk)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I took a slightly different tack after seeing a graph of the situation.  If we simply subtract one circle equation from the other, we obtain

$$ 2bx \ - \ 2cy \ - \ 2a^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$

which is the equation of the line through $ \ P \ $ and $ \ Q \ , $ since this is telling us something about the intersections of the two circles.  (And, I agree, we don't really need to know the coordinates of those points.)  This line, containing the chord $ \ PQ \ $ in both circles, has a slope of $ \ \frac{b}{c} \ . $  But the line through the circle centers $ \ A \ $ and $ \ B \  $ has slope $ \ - \frac{c}{b} \ , $ so these two lines are perpendicular.  This means that the line $ \ AB \ $ contains a diameter of each circle, and potentially the one we seek.

Now since  $ \ A \ $ and $ \ B \  $ lie on this putative common circle, one might simply choose the segment $ \ AB \ $ to *be* a diameter, which would put the center of this circle at the midpoint $ \ ( \frac{b}{2} \ , \ \frac{c}{2} ) $ . If this circle is to pass through the origin, the Pythagorean Theorem tells us that $ \ r^2 \ = \ \frac{b^2}{4} + \frac{c^2}{4} \ . $

We have thereby described a circle through $ \ O \ , \ A \ , \ $ and $ \ B \ , \ (x - \frac{b}{2} )^2 \ + \ (y - \frac{c}{2} )^2 \ = \ \frac{b^2}{4} + \frac{c^2}{4} \ . $  Does it pass through $ \ P \ $ and $ \ Q \ $ ?  This circle equation can be re-written as  $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ = \ bx + cy \ . $  Inserting this into the two circle equations to replace their first two terms yields

$$ bx \ + \ cy \ - \  2cy \ - \ a^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ bx \ + \ cy \ - \  2bx \ + \ a^2 \ = \ 0  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ bx \  - \  cy \ - \ a^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ -bx \ + \ cy \ + \ a^2 \ = \ 0 . $$

These are *both* exactly the equation for the line containing the chord $ \ PQ \  $ (after a scalar multiplication). So this chord passes through the intersections of all three circles and thus the new circle passes through all five points.

[I am proposing this solution not because it is fundamentally *distinct* from **coffeemath**'s, but only because it uses a couple different geometrical facts.  Either way, the analytical portion is simple enough that I imagine there is probably a "classical" geometric proof.]

Comment: Though the solution is a good one, but do you think that finding the circle to be centred at $(b/2,c/2)$ is a little luck and a matter of co-incidence, I mean this might not have been the case, considering the circle to have diameter of $AB$ might not work so good. I am a little doubtful on that, please explain that part.

Comment: I would agree that that step seems a bit intuitive.  However, it now occurs to me that one can argue immediately that placing $ \ C \ $ at the midpoint means triangles $ \ OAC \ $ and $ \ OBC \ $ are isosceles, and that $ \ CA \ , \ CB \ , $ and $ \ CO \ $ all have the same length.  The issue, as I see it, is not in establishing that you can put a circle through $ \ O \ , \ A \ , $ and $ \ B \ , $ because it is always possible to do so.  The essential part of the proof is in showing that this circle _also_ passes through $ \ P \ $ and $ \ Q \ . $

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1$ be the circle defined by the equation $x^2+y^2-2cy-a^2=0$ and $C_2$ be the circle defined by the equation $x^2+y^2-2bx+a^2=0.$ Now $$x^2+y^2-2cy-a^2=0 \\ \implies (x-0)^2+(y-c)^2=\left(\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\right)^2 \text{and}\\ x^2+y^2-2bx+a^2=0\\ \implies (x-b)^2+(y-0)^2=\left(\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\right)^2.$$ This implies that $C_1$ is a circle with it's centre as $A=(0,c)$ and radius $R_1=\sqrt{a^2+c^2}$ and $C_2$ is a circle with it's centre as $A=(b,0)$ and radius $R_2=\sqrt{b^2-a^2}.$

Now in $\Delta AQB$, we have $$AB^2=(b-0)^2+(0-c)^2=b^2+c^2, \\ AQ^2=R_1^2=a^2+c^2 \text{ and } BQ^2=R_2^2=b^2-a^2, \\ \implies AB^2=AQ^2+BQ^2.$$

Therefore $\Delta AQB$ is a right-angled triangle with $\angle AQB=90^0.$

Now we know that $\Delta AQB \cong \Delta APB,$ which implies that $\angle APB=90^0$.

Therefore, in quadrilateral $AQBP$, we have $\angle APB+\angle AQB=180^0,$ which implies that $AQBP$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. This implies that points $A,Q,B,P$ lie on a circle having $AB$ as the diameter.

Now, we also have $AOB=90^0,$ which implies that $O$ lies on the same circle defined by the points $A,Q,B,P$.

Hence, the points $A,B,P,Q$ and $O$ lie on a circle.